# Send Recv from client to server socket by establish TCP Connection only once

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am working on a client/server solution in C++.

From the client, I am sending data to my server, and from this server I am sending to another server. I am able to configure port and IP address, and am able to send successfully.

But, the other server (which is not on my side) needs to establish only one TCP connection from my side, after that only sending and receiving needs to happen.

If I am connecting twice (say from two clients at the same time), it shows connection refused.

Part of the code is shown below:

```
while ((len = stream->receive(input, sizeof(input)-1)) > 0 )
{
    input[len] = NULL;
    //Code Addition by Srini starts here

    //Client declaration
    TCPConnector* connector_client = new TCPConnector();
    printf("ip_client = %s\tport_client = %s\tport_client_int = %d\n", ip_client.c_str(), port_client.c_str(),atoi(port_client.c_str()));
    TCPStream* stream_client = connector_client->connect(ip_client.c_str(), atoi(port_client.c_str()));

    //Client declaration ends
    if (stream_client)
    {
        //message = "Is there life on Mars?";
        //stream_client->send(message.c_str(), message.size());
        //printf("sent - %s\n", message.c_str());

        stream_client->send(input, sizeof(input));
        printf("sent - %s\n", input);
        len = stream_client->receive(line, sizeof(line));
        line[len] = NULL;
        printf("received - %s\n", line);
        delete stream_client;
    }

    //Code Additon by Srini ends here

    stream->send(line, len);
    printf("thread %lu, echoed '%s' back to the client\n",
        (long unsigned int)self(), line);
}
```

The full thread code where receiving from client, sending to server, receiving from server, and sending to client is shown in the below link:

https://pastebin.com/UmPQJ70w

How can I change my design flow?  Even in a basic diagram of client/server program.  When the client calls `connect()`, then the server calls `accept()` every time, then sending/receiving happens.  So, what can be done to modify the flow so that the client can connect only once?

Answer (score 0):

Your intermediate server (which is acting as a proxy, so lets call it that) needs to maintain a single connection to the other server and delegate messaging with it in parallel to the messaging being done between your proxy and its clients.

I would suggest creating a separate thread whose sole task is to maintain that connection to the other server, and to send/receive messages with it.

When a client sends a message to your proxy, place the message in a thread-safe queue somewhere.  Have the thread check the queue periodically and send any queued messages to the other server.

When the other server sends a message to your proxy, the thread can receive it and forward it to the appropriate client.